# how to call 2 JavaScript methods in the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, google-maps-api-3

i have this class with a few methods more code here [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/ilumov/27/edit)

```
var Maps = (function () {

function Maps() {

}

Maps.prototype.getCoord = function () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.onPositionSuccess, this.onPositionError);
};

Maps.prototype.getWatchCoord = function () {
    var options = { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 3000 };
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(this.onWatchSuccess, this.onWatchError, options);
};

Maps.prototype.onPositionSuccess = function (position) {
    var pos = {
        'latitude'          : position.coords.latitude,
        'longitude'         : position.coords.longitude
    };
    console.log(pos);
};

Maps.prototype.onWatchSuccess = function (position) {
    var pos = {
        'latitude'          : position.coords.latitude,
        'longitude'         : position.coords.longitude
    };
    console.log(pos);
};

Maps.prototype.onWatchError = function (error) {
    console.log(error.code);
};
Maps.prototype.onPositionError = function (error) {
    console.log(error.code);
};

return Maps;

})();

var maps = new Maps();
    maps.getCoord();
```

what i am trying to do is if `getCoord()` is a success then do a call to `getWatchCoord()` and compare the `latitude` and `longitude`. If they are the same don't run `getWatchCoord()`

Im trying to do this inside that Maps class if possible.

I've tried a few ways but it seems i cant call `getWatchCoord()` inside `onPositionSuccess()`
not i can set `var x = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition....` and then `return pos;` inside the success callback <- it wont return anything

Any ideas?

Comment: Try making getWatchCoord a function within onPositionSuccess.  If it needs to be re-usable, can always use apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using jQuery? If you are, then do this:

```
var Maps = (function () {

function Maps() {

}

Maps.prototype.getCoord = function () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition($.proxy(this.onPositionSuccess, this), $.proxy(this.onPositionError, this));
};

Maps.prototype.getWatchCoord = function () {
    var options = { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 3000 };
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition($.proxy(this.onWatchSuccess, this), $.proxy(this.onWatchError, this), options);
};

Maps.prototype.onPositionSuccess = function (position) {
    var pos = {
        'latitude'          : position.coords.latitude,
        'longitude'         : position.coords.longitude
    };
    console.log(pos);

    //call getWatchCoord
    this.getWatchCoord();
};

Maps.prototype.onWatchSuccess = function (position) {
    var pos = {
        'latitude'          : position.coords.latitude,
        'longitude'         : position.coords.longitude
    };
    console.log(pos);
};

Maps.prototype.onWatchError = function (error) {
    console.log(error.code);
};
Maps.prototype.onPositionError = function (error) {
    console.log(error.code);
};

return Maps;

})();

var maps = new Maps();
    maps.getCoord();
```

'this' will be global when entering the success callback if you do not pass a callback function that is scope with the right 'this' which is why I used [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) above. Now this is untested so I do not know what other problems you have here.

Comment: i see, interesting approach using `$.proxy()`. I was interested in a VanilaJS approach, but this works. thanks

Comment: one more thing. What if i want to `return pos;` from `onWatchSuccess()`, then do `var x = this.getWatchCoord(); console.log(x)` ?

Comment: i figure it out, i pass the first `pos` int the `options` obj of `getWatchCoord()`